# RStudio Default Workspace (Window Panes)

Tags: r, rstudio, pane

Somehow, a few weeks ago, my RStudio window panes shifted. I really hate how only 3 window panes are shown. Can anyone tell me how to the default where all four windows are shown all times and the console on the bottom left?

This is how mine looks right now:

[image]

Comment: Can you check `Tools-> Global Options -> Pane Layout`

Comment: There are still 4 window panes shown, if we look closely we can see the label of the 'History' tabe in the lower left corner. The pane is just vertically minimized. We should be able to drag'n drop its top border to adjust the size. As already suggested we can also change some of the layout in the `Global Options`

Comment: @dario - unfortunately, when i try to drag it up, the history tab maximizes and it concurrently minimizes the console... it's really a drag!

Comment: @akrun - unfortunately, i've done that. i need more specific instructions...

Comment: So you tried akruns suggestion to move the position of the console to the bottom left? But there it's still shown in the top rigth??

Comment: i got it now! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try selecting the drop down arrow near the four-pane button in the menu bar.  Select show all panes and console on left.  Then resize the pane by grabbing the edge and dragging or toggling the minimize buttons on/off.  Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: oh- thank you. This was such a stupid thing. I hit a key and all my widows shifted around, and disappeared.